# Why does newLISP limit string literals to 2048 characters?

Tags: string, memory, newlisp

I'm trying to write usage instructions for this `newLISP` program I've made but it keeps complaining about the string being too long.

```
ERR: string token too long : "$$$$$$$$&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&"
```

I spent some ten minutes cursing `newLISP` and coming up with paranoid theories like, maybe you shouldn't have quotes in the string or maybe it'll work when I use raw strings(`{}`), until I started chopping the string. It reached a point where the message dissappeared leaving the help message very unhelpful. Turns out `newLISP` doesn't like strings that have more than `2048(2^11)` characters. Soo,

**Why put a limit on the number of characters in a string literal?**
**Why 2048 characters?**

Increasing cell memory to `128MB`(saw it the manual) doesn't change anything. The only solution that works now(a hackish one), is splitting the help string into two strings each under `2048` characters then concatenating them with `string`.
The other strange thing is that any string that has `2048+` characters is printed differently in the repl:

```
> (dup "&" 2048)
    [text]&&&&&&&&&&&&&& .....
           ......
                &&&&&&&&&&&&&&&[/text]


> (dup "&" 2040)
    "&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&& .....
        .....
                &&&&&&&&&&&&&&&"
```

Answer (score 1):

There are three ways to do strings:

- in quotes - escape characters are processed - limited to 2048 chars
- in braces - no escape characters are processed - limited to 2048 chars
- in tags - no escapes are processed - unlimited length

From the manual:

> Quoted strings cannot exceed 2,048 characters. Longer strings should use the [text] and [/text] tag delimiters. newLISP automatically uses these tags for string output longer than 2,048 characters.

Strings can be quite long:

```
> (quiet (set 's (dup "&" 10E8))) ; don't bother to show the string :)
> (length s)
1000000000
> (10000 20 s)
"&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&"
>
```

The only problem you'll have is when you want to process source code in strings that might contain a `[/text]` tag before you want the string to really end. It doesn't look like you're at that point yet... :)

Comment: How would you do that? It seems to allow nesting of `[text]` tags. Why specifically `2048` characters?

Comment: @Segfault I suppose it's got to be *some* number, and 2048 seems no better or worse than any other...:) You could try asking the author of newLISP in person if you want the definitive reason.